# Customizing the Spring Roo generated GWT user interface

Tags: java, gwt, code-generation, spring-roo

How does one go about customizing the GWT user interface that Spring Roo automatically generates?

Am I supposed to change the Roo-generated source files? If so, will that not be clobbered the next time Roo runs?

Or do I need to configure something in Roo and then rebuild the GWT sources?

In this particular case, the column widths of the domain object list view need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For as far as I know, this is indeed not possible yet in Spring Roo. As you rightfully stated, the by Spring Roo generated files will be regenerated by Spring Roo when you alter your entities. There are some solutions, but these all are but small workarounds and don't offer the actual programming experience you'd expect or want. The Spring Roo team (and community) has already addressed this issue though and is working hard to solve this. So expect this to be improved real soon. For more information, check the following links to the Spring Roo Forum and Spring Roo JIRA:

- Spring Roo Forum thread: [Roo GWT customization](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=97611)
- Spring Roo JIRA issue: [Roo update is too destructive](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/ROO-1280)
- Spring Roo JIRA issue: [Manual Created Request Interfaces get deleted](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1443)

Comment: Hmm. I suppose that while this situation is rather unacceptable, this answer is. :-)  Maybe we can revisit this topic half a year down the road or so.

Answer (score 1):

May I humbly suggest [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org)? It generates Spring MVC, GWT and other interfaces at runtime, so there is no regeneration step (and nothing to get 'clobbered') as your entities change.

Comment: For that particular project, Roo was mandated. Metawidget looks neat, I'll give it a try next time round. I certainly prefer to get rid off autogenerated source code. Note that the problem here was not with Roo autogenerating stuff per-se, but with the inability to customize how it does that. Do you have a link to a Metawidget tutorial that shows how to influence the generated UI (such as column headers or widths)?

Comment: Sure: http://metawidget.org/doc/reference/en/html/ch01.html

A video walkthrough is also available: http://metawidget.org/videos.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a ui.xml file generated by ROO, just rename it and refer to it in the .java file.

e.g You want to modify the file PizzaDetailsView.ui.xml:

Rename it to PizzaDetailsViewPrime.ui.xml
Then add this line just before the interface Binder declaration:

> @UiTemplate("PizzaDetailsViewPrime.ui.xml")